# I can't find syntax error from a PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, query, syntax, aggregate-filter

A similarly structured query works on [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/r53IU49t) but I get a syntax error at or near "AND"

```
LINE 9:             AND h.paivamaara BETWEEN '2020-12-03'::date AND ...
                    ^
```

and I can't find any errors in the following query. The table contains no data with the queried ids 3 or 4 but that should not cause a syntax error.

```
SELECT 
  havikki * 100 / valmistettu AS Kaikki, 
  (havikki - Juomat) * 100 / valmistettu  AS "Ilman juomia", 
  Juomat
FROM (
  SELECT 
  SUM (h.havikin_maara) 
  FILTER (
    WHERE h.havikkityyppi_id = 3 OR h.havikkityyppi_id = 4
    AND h.paivamaara BETWEEN {start} AND {stop}
  ) AS havikki,
  SUM (h.valmistettu_maara)
  FILTER (
    WHERE h.havikkityyppi_id = 3 OR h.havikkityyppi_id = 4
    AND h.paivamaara BETWEEN {start} AND {stop}
  ) AS valmistettu,
  SUM (h.havikin_maara) 
  FILTER (        
    WHERE h.havikkityyppi_id = 3 OR h.havikkityyppi_id = 4
    AND h.tuote_id = 10 OR h.tuote_id = 17
    AND h.paivamaara BETWEEN {start} AND {stop}
    ) AS Juomat
  FROM havikit h
);
```

Could someone point out what causing the syntax error? `SELECT * FROM havikit` does what is expected, here is an example row:
`(3, 1, 1, 15, 'Pikkuporkkanat', 0.3, 0.0, 1.0, 96, 0, datetime.date(2023, 9, 11), 'NaN')`. `havikkityyppi_id` is the third column.

Comment: Why posting `a similar query` and not the one with the issue on the fiddle ?

Comment: A query with syntax error fails before Postgres even looks at any table rows. Also, there is no syntax error (after substituting proper values for `{start}` and `{stop}`) - assuming Postgres 16. Older versions would require an alias for the subquery. Another case where disclosing the **Postgres version** up front would be instrumental.

Comment: There was a typo elswhere in the code. Fixing that removed the problem. The question can be closed.